# Ajax request to pages within a windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I am building a windows phone mobile app with phonegap. I need to get some content from a particular page within the application...This is what I have for now:

```
function getXMLHTTPRequest() {
try {
req = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch(err1) {
try { 
req = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
} catch (err2) {
try {
req = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
} catch (err3) { 
req = false;
}
}
 }
  return req;
   }
   var first_req = getXMLHTTPRequest();


    var firsturl = '/books/Col.xml';

    first_req.open('GET', firsturl, true);
    first_req.onreadystatechange = createResponse;
    first_req.send(null);

    function createResponse() 
    {
    if (first_req.readyState == 4) {

if(first_req.status == 200) 
{
 navigator.notification.alert(
        'sucess',
        doNot,
        'success',
        'Worked'
        );

}

else {
 navigator.notification.alert(
        "request.status = "+first_req.status,
        doNot,
        'Error',
        'Try Again'
        );



}
```

it doesn't work, the else block runs and alerts request.status = 0

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: have you tried removing the first / in '/books/Col.xml', so 'books/Col.xml' ?

Comment: Yes,  I have, still doesn work.

Comment: how about www/books/Col.xml?

Comment: did you put your book folder in the www folder of your phonegap project? books/Col.xml should be the correct url. (at least it's the kind of path I use, difference is I load json files and use jquery for the xhttprequest)

Comment: Yes it is in the www folder of the project...

Comment: I changed the code to this, but still not working...is there some issues specific to the windows platform that is causing the problem???
 `$jq.ajax({
    url: "books/Col.xml"  
    }).done(function(data) {
       
     navigator.notification.alert(
   'Success',
   doNot,
   'Error',
   'Try Again'
   );

    })
    .fail(function() {
       navigator.notification.alert(
   'Check Internet Connection',
   doNot,
   'Success',
   'worked'
   );
    });`